# Hierarchy structure for these entities

Tags: java, oop

I need to define an object oriented class hierarchy structure for the following entities: Computer,Processor,Celeron Processor,Athlon Processor,HP,Dell,Mouse,Keyboard.

I came up with something as follows:

```
public interface Computer
{
    public void mouse();
    public void keyboard();
}
public class Processor
{
   public void Celeron(){ }
   public void Athlon(){ }
}
public class HP extends Processor,implements Computer
{
}
```

Can someone point out what is wrong with this design?Also,if anyone can suggest a better design it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Before we do your homework for you, can you first write a short summary why you came up with such a design? Currently it seems that you just threw something together that happens to compile. :-P

Comment: Mouse and Keyboard are common to all computers,so each brand is free to define it's implementation.A brand can also override the processor it wants and can define it's own implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I would rather say, a `Computer` *has a* `Processor`.
`HP` *is a* `Computer`; `Dell` *is a* `Computer`.
`Celeron` *is a* `Processor`; `Athlon` *is a* `Processor`.
And a `Computer` *has a* `Mouse` as well as a `Keyboard`.
*has a*: Association.
*is a*: Inheritance.

Comment: To expand a bit on Flinsch's answer, you basically have only two relations: *is-a* and *has-a*.
*is-a* should give you an interface like `Keyboard` itself while *has-a* should give you an interface like `HasKeyboard { public Keyboard getKeyboard(); }`. Interfaces higher up in the hierarchy would extend lower interfaces. E.g. `Computer extends HasKeyboard`.

You don't have to be that verbose with your interfaces though as this seems to be an exercise you should create as many as you can for practice.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like the following would probably do:

```
public interface IInputDevice {}
public interface IProcessor {}

public abstract class Computer 
{
    IInputDevice[] inputDevices;
    IProcessor processor;
}

public class Mouse implements IInputDevice {}
public class KeyBoard implements IInputDevice {}

public class AthlonProcessor implements IProcessor {}
public class CeleronProcessor implements IProcessor {}

public abstract class HP extends Computer
{

}

public abstract class Dell extends Computer
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of programming language, stop and consider how to build an *information model* to represent the things in question. You have a few kinds of relationships at your disposal:

- *is-a*

  Some thing or concept is a refinement of or interchangeable with some other concept, such as a "Celeron processor" being a processor. Inheritance can model this relationship, but not all inheritance is meant to model this relationship.
- *has-a*

  Some kind of thing contains or is associated with some other thing, such as a computer having a keyboard connected to it. Member varibles or fields in structures can model this relationship, both as by-value *containment* (including controlling the life-cycle of the contained thing) or by-reference *aggregation* (usually not controlling the life-cycle of the associated thing).
- *uses*

  More general than *has-a*, one thing requires a reference to some other thing to get its job done. This can be represented as a required parameter to a member function or method.

For your problem, we can see that a Celeron *is a* processor, that a computer *has a* processor (one or more), that HP *is a* company that *sells* computers, or, alternately, that a computer *has a* responsible vendor (one or more) and HP *is a* vendor. HP could sell mice too, and a computer can have zero or more mice connected.

I'm reluctant to tell you how to use Java to build such a model. There are many solutions, and exploring more than one solution also offers insight into why [the *relational model*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) is more expressive for information modeling than Java's class and interface facility.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather say, a Computer has a Processor.
HP is a Computer; Dell is a Computer.
Celeron is a Processor; Athlon is a Processor.
And a Computer has a Mouse as well as a Keyboard.
has a: Association.
is a: Inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing mouse and keyboard, and celeron and athlon as methods. They should be separated Classes. Computer should be a class too and not an interface.

And I don't see why would you want "HP" to extend processor and to implement Computer.

Comment: So will HP or Dell be an object of Computer class or it will be another class which extends Computer,Celeron,Athlon,mouse,keyboard?I do not see how everything will be connected.